# react counter don't update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I will do the counter operation with React, but when I click the buttons, I can't see the result of increasing or decreasing instantly on the screen. Can you tell me what I should add to this code part?
I'm getting the cartItem.quantity data from an array, I don't need to re-introduce it in the state. Do I need to assign new value in this.setState?

export default class CartList extends Component {
renderAll() {
return (

{this.props.cart.map((cartItem) => (
<Card
className="m-5"
style={{
width: "18rem",
}}
>


{cartItem.product.productName}

{cartItem.product.quantityPerUnit}

{cartItem.product.unitPrice}
{cartItem.product.unitsInStock}
{cartItem.quantity}

<Button color="danger" onClick={() => (cartItem.quantity -= 1)}>
-

```
            <Input
              className="text-center"
              placeholder={cartItem.quantity}
              style={{
                background: "lightgrey",
                fontSize: "20px",
                width: "100%",
              }}
            />

            <Button
              color="success"
              onClick={() => (cartItem.quantity += 1)}
            >
              +
            </Button>
          </CardText>
        </CardBody>
      </Card>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

}

Comment: Is `cartItem` state? You need to use a state setter function to updare it.

Comment: Can you provide the code for the `cartItem` state?

Comment: In whatever React tutorial(s) you're using, you've missed quite possibly the most central and fundamental concept in React... using and updating *state*.  Just directly modifying variables doesn't trigger a component to re-render.

Comment: All you are missing is a setState call. 
setState() method enqueues all of the updates made to the component state and instructs React to re-render the component and its children with the updated state.

Comment: You should update your question with the code that shows how you're currently initialising state because it looks to be more complex than on first glance. For example you're refererencing `cartItem` - how many cart items are in the state? Is state an array of `cartItem` objects, and you only want to update the quantity of one of those objects?  [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Answer (score 1):

In React.js you have to update the variables with the help of state's setter.

For example,

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
```

So to update the counter variable value I have to update it with `setCounter`

So in your case you have to create `cartItem` state

```
<Button color="danger" onClick={() => updateCounter("dec")}>
  -
</Button>

<h3 style={{ background: "lightgrey", width: "100%" }}>
  {cartItem.quantity}
</h3>

<Button color="success" onClick={() => updateCounter("inc")}>
  +
</Button>
```

And the Js function is as follows :

```
const [cartItem, setCartItem] = useState({}); // cart item is an object which contains other fields as well
const updateCounter = (action) => {
    const data = { ...cartItem };
    action === "inc" ? data.quantity++ : data.quantity--;
    setCartItem(data);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In React, states are immutable, which means that you cannot change its value directly.

If you are using a function component:

```js
const Counter = () => {

   const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Counter is {{counter}}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter+1)} >Increment</button>
    </div>
  )

}
```

As you can see, I can't update directly my state counter, but I have to use setCounter().

You can see the official documentation: [Here](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Comment: setCounter(counter+1) this might work in here but the best practice is never update the count value like this - instead write this like :
setCounter((prevCounter)=>{prevCounter+1})